# Composite not grabbing excess horizontal space for TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt, composite, treeviewer

I'm trying to fill a composite horizontally from data coming from a TreeViewer, without success. If you have any suggestions, I would me most thankful.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
 private Composite composite;
 private ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

    composite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.BEGINNING, true, false));
    composite.setLayout(createNoMarginLayout(1, false));

    scrolledComposite.setContent(composite);

    compositeNdal = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
    compositeNdal.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));
    compositeNdal.setLayout(createNoMarginLayout(1, true));
    compositeNdal.setVisible(true);



    treeViewerNdalEditor = new TreeViewer(compositeNdal,SWT.BORDER|SWT.FILL);
    /* (computing the tree part goes here)  */

 public static GridLayout createNoMarginLayout(int numColumns, boolean makeColumnsEqualWidth) {
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(numColumns, makeColumnsEqualWidth);
        layout.verticalSpacing = 0;
        layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
        layout.marginTop = 0;
        layout.marginBottom = 0;
        layout.marginLeft = 0;
        layout.marginRight = 0;
        layout.marginWidth = 0;
        layout.marginHeight = 0;
        return layout;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set layout data on the tree to tell the parent composite layout how to handle the tree:

```
treeViewerNdalEditor.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```